# Populate <div> in form when user selects from dropdown in CakePHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, cakephp

I have a form where a user can select a rating from 1-5. Each of these options is pulled from a linked table and all works well.

What I would like to do, is have a DIV to the side of the select box that will update containing a more detailed description of the selected option.  Example:

User selects:
1 - EXCELLENT
DIV populates with:
Excellent - Everything is working as expected, and you have no complaints!

User selects:
4 - POOR
DIV populates with:
POOR - you would rather die than come to work.

I might work on my descriptions a bit, but you get the idea.

I understand that in the AJAX helper, I can use observeField, but when I pull up the documentation from http://book.cakephp.org/view/1368/observeField#!/view/1358/AJAX  I see that the AJAX helper has been deprecated in favor of JsHelper + HtmlHelper.

What is the proper way to do what I intend?
The data is in loadLevel, with the div contents needing to show loadLevels.description when computters.load_level_id is changed. (this makes sense to me, but if I'm being unclear, please be nice to the CakePHP novice)

EDIT: I'm using CakePHP 1.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the Javascript engine / framework you chose to use. So for example if you are using jQuery, you fist need to include it:

```
var $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'));
```

Then you need to load it in your view:

```
echo $this->Html->script('jquery');
```

Then you can call the functions of the library or make your own. Here is a link to the various "built in" methods. This may help push you in the right direction.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1592/Js#!/view/1593/Methods

The section you may be most interested in is: **event($type, $content, $options = array())**